# Julia set data from DataFrames to JSON

Tags: json, dataframe, julia, genie.jl

related post: [DataFrames to Database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72695370/dataframes-to-database-tables)

Indeed, my plan is data passing from DataFrame to json. I am trying to use Genie frame work and Genie.json, the sample data is as following,

```
Row  │ id     name   address      age      sex    
     │ Int64  String String?    String?  String? 
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 1     Ono     Kyoto        60       m
   2 │ 2     Serena  PA           38       F
   3 │ 3     Edita   Slovakia     ３２       F
```

and this data packed to res as DataFrames, then

```
json( Dict( "alldata" => res ))
```

the json data is lined order by columns.

(A):{"alldata":{"columns":[[1,2,3], ["Ono","Serana","Edita"],["Kyoto","PA","Slovakia"],["60","38","３２"],["m","f","f"]]}}

But, of course, I would like to get each row like this

(B):{"alldata":{"columns":[[1,"Ono","Kyoto","60","m"],[2,"Serana","PA","38","f"],[3,"Edita","Slovakia","３２","f"]]}}

I posted the same question on Genie community then got answer using JSON3 package after serialization. That procedure made sense, however I wonder are there any ideas alike do not use serialize processing. **The ideal process is direct pass from Dataframes to json to realize (B) json form data.**

To json by serializing

```
oDf::DataFrame = SearchLight.query( sSelect )
if !isempty(oDf)
    for oRow in eachrow(oDf)
        _iid::Int = oRow.id
        _sname::String = oRow.name
            ・
            ・
        push!( aTmp["alldata"], Dict("columns"=>[_iid,_sname,_saddress,_sage,_ssex]))
    end
    aTmp["data_ready"] = 1
end

sRetJ = JSON3.write(aTmp)
```

I looked at DataFrames.jl but did not find the solution, maybe the book has it, but not yet.
Thanks any advances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the following:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[11, 12, 13])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1     11
   2 │     2     12
   3 │     3     13

julia> Genie.Renderer.Json.json(Dict("alldata" => "columns" => Vector.(eachrow(df))))
HTTP.Messages.Response:
"""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"alldata":{"columns":[[1,11],[2,12],[3,13]]}}"""
```

(however, it is strange that you want to call this `"columns"` while these are rows of your data)

If you want to retain column names you can do:

```
julia> Genie.Renderer.Json.json(Dict("alldata" => "columns" => copy.(eachrow(df))))
HTTP.Messages.Response:
"""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"alldata":{"columns":[{"a":1,"b":11},{"a":2,"b":12},{"a":3,"b":13}]}}"""
```

Comment: Awesome, this is the solution that I wanted. Thank you again, prof. Kaminski. I did not have an idea such like that.
Indeed I have just started to an open source project that is written in Julia, despite I am newbie in julia. You help me a lot. Thank you so much, again, Dr. Kaminski.